# A permutation and combination problem about the number of connections in a sequence of n numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, sequences-and-series, permutations

There is a sequence of n numbers as 1,2,3,...,n
How many combinations of the connections between two numbers in the sequence without overlaping?

```
Take a sequence 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 for example:  
combination 1: (1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6),(6,7),(7,8),(8,9),(9,10) is allowable
combination 2: (1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8),(9,10) is allowable
combination 3: (1,3),(3,5),(6,8) is allowable
combination 4: (2,6),(7,8) is allowable
combination 5: (2,5),(4,6) is unallowable, because the overlaping exsits
```

Comment: Show your work, as they say

Comment: I have tried for a long time, but I failed.

Comment: Assuming that "connections" like $(1,1)$ are not allowed, for $n=2,3,4,5$ I get $2,5,13,34$, which is every other Fibonacci number, https://oeis.org/A001519 (but OEIS has several other sequences that start with those four terms). What does it have to do with graph theory, please?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But how to prove the number of combinations is the every other Fibonacci number or other special number? And whether a formula about the number of combinations can be given ?

Comment: I say, WHAT DOES IT HAVE TO DO WITH GRAPH THEORY?

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to do with the connection paths in graph theory?

Answer (score 1):

As Gerry Myerson comments, there are $F_{2n-1}$ such combinations for $\{1,\dots,n\}$. One way to see this is via a bijection with the Morse code sequences of length $2n-2$ that looks like this:

$$
\begin{align*}
&{\cdot}\;{\cdot}\;{\cdot}\;{\cdot}\;{\cdot}\;{\cdot} &&\emptyset\\
&{\cdot}\;{\cdot}\;{\cdot}\;{\cdot}\;- &&(34)\\
&{\cdot}\;{\cdot}\;{\cdot}\;-{\cdot} &&(24)\\
&{\cdot}\;{\cdot}\;-{\cdot}\;{\cdot} &&(23)\\
&{\cdot}-\;{\cdot}\;{\cdot}\;{\cdot} &&(13)\\
&-\;{\cdot}\;{\cdot}\;{\cdot}\;{\cdot} &&(12)\\
&{\cdot}\;{\cdot}\;-\;- &&(23)(34)\\
&{\cdot}\;-\;{\cdot}\;- &&(13)(34)\\
&{\cdot}\;-\;-\;{\cdot} &&(14)\\
&-\;{\cdot}\;{\cdot}\;- &&(12)(34)\\
&-\;{\cdot}-{\cdot} &&(12)(24)\\
&-\;-\;{\cdot}\;{\cdot} &&(12)(23)\\
&-\;-\;- &&(12)(23)(34)
\end{align*}
$$
There are $n-1$ pairs of dots, representing the $n-1$ adjacent numbers $(12)$, $(23)$, ..., $(n\!-\!1\;n)$ in order. For example, $(12)(23)$ is represented by $--\cdot\;\cdot$, since the first two pairs are activated. Lines joining two pairs combine them, so $(13)$ is represented by $\cdot-\cdot\cdot\cdot$ since it joins $(12)$ with $(23)$.

It is then easily seen that the Morse code sequences of length $n$ (where a dot has length $1$ and a dash has length $2$) are counted by the Fibonacci numbers $F_{n+1}$, since every length $n$ Morse code sequence is either a dot followed by a length $n-1$ Morse code sequence, or a dash followed by a length $n-2$ Morse code sequence.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While, I am confused about why ⋅⋅⋅⋅− is represented by (34) rather than (56)? And what does 3 or 4 mean?